# how do i save a winform to pdf using the save as dialog

Tags: vb.net

I have a winform with a menu strip and an option to Save As.  What I would like to do is to give the user the option to save that winform as a .pdf.

Can this be done?

Comment: -1 You didn't even google `save winform as a .pdf`.

Comment: I did, and did not find what I was looking for. That is why I posted the question here.

Comment: @user2494051 .. what do you mean by **to save that winform as a .pdf** ? .. is that mean you want to save the onscreen image ?

Comment: Yes I want to save the onscreen as a pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate PDF with content of form, you have to look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library.